# xcodebuild can't connect to the Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode6

I get errors like this:

```
2014-10-16 13:14:50.996 xcodebuild[6775:1007] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Unable to connect to "com.apple.instruments.deviceservice.lockdown" (Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fabd4043b30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown})
```

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and am trying to run my tests via Jenkins. I only have this problem from the command line: running the tests in Xcode is fine.

I've tried deleting the contents of `DerivedData`, uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, and rebooting the machine – nothing seems to help.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes and no. I still see them occasionally, but I think they weren't actually a breaking problem: I think my Jenkins builds were failing because I hadn't upgraded to a version of `ocunit2junit` that supports Xcode 6. Once I did that, my builds complete.

Comment: I didn't find any updates for Xcode 6. how do you run the test build?

Comment: @dollar8: [Version 1.4](http://rubygems.org/gems/ocunit2junit/versions/1.4) adds [support for Xcode 6](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit/commit/eea65c14796819bfb298f6de425ca8f57d537a01).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and killing the simulator before running xcodebuild helped.

> killall -9 "iOS Simulator"

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to help for me.

Comment: This didn't help me either.

Comment: killing simulators helped me